# SugarCRM get_entry_list REST API call using REST client or POSTMAN

Tags: rest, api, sugarcrm

I am going thru the documentation and examples related to calling REST APIs for SugarCRM using Chrome REST client or PostMan but most of the examples are PHP and I am not finding a good way to find a proper request and other parameters to be mentioned so that I can get the successful response from the API. I was trying get_entry_list. Can someone please help by providing a working REST API request for this API which I can run on REST client or postman?

I also would like to know if I want to build a SugarCRM connector for my application, which set of APIs I should use? Should I go with REST or SOAP and any supporting arguments to choose one over another?

Thanks